# Como fazer slidedown e slideup da navbar quando der scroll na pagina

Tags: jquery, rolamento, nav-bar

Olá, sou iniciante em jQuery e estou tentando configurar a navbar do meu site para que quando der scroll down, a navbar esconda e fique apenas um botão para que abra a navbar, e quando der scroll up até o máximo essa botão fique invisivel. Gostaria de saber como pode ser feito isso.

A div que da navbar é a seguinte:

```html
<div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="height:170px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <h1><svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120px" height="140px" viewBox="0 0 992.32 807.5"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#124466;}.cls-1,.cls-2,.cls-3{fill-rule:evenodd;}.cls-2{fill:#ea7f0a;}.cls-3{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M952.54 373.61c-61.84-56.16-124.37-113-186.35-168.29-52.16-46.55-103.37-93.95-155.13-140.15C580.19 37.63 551.42 4.28 498.76 0h-3.37C460.58 2.86 435.33 18.66 414 37s-41.33 37.85-62.11 56.28c-41.77 37.17-83.07 74.69-124.57 112.34-40.9 37.15-83.69 74.32-124.84 112-20.32 18.66-41.16 37.93-62.09 56.3C19.32 392.41 2.1 416.52.32 452.28H0v8.26c4.18 42.44 25.79 67.43 70.38 69.46v.61c-1.76 57.31 1.39 118.75-.92 176.56-2.37 59.4 22 97.21 77.41 100.36h704.39c40.7-3.49 61.85-26.93 70.07-61.5 2.89-12.16 3.37-25.09 3.37-40.7 0-57.66-.84-117.7-.61-175 44.52-1.68 64-28.42 68.24-70.38v-8c-2.08-35.59-18.95-59.41-39.79-78.34z"/><path class="cls-2" d="M907.87 436.34c-.23-4-5.11-7.88-8.87-11.32-39.16-35.85-78.32-71.35-117-106.77l-24.57-22.48c-3.37-3-6.75-6-10-9.12l-140.11-128.2c-31.82-29.04-63.74-58.17-95.4-87.17-4.72-4.31-9.75-12.07-16.52-11.32-4.51.5-10 7.15-14.69 11.32s-9 8.39-12.85 11.93c-94.78 86.31-190.74 170.53-285.18 257.34-29.15 26.8-60.39 55.18-90.57 82-4 3.56-11.33 8.65-11.93 12.85-1.74 12.15 12.29 9.79 23.25 9.79h53.89v245.4c0 11-1.65 23.36 9.49 22 8.77-1 7-10.7 7-21.73V451.33c0-6 .88-12.31-.31-16.83-1.89-7.24-9.91-5.81-19-5.81h-44.04C235.96 314.52 364.08 199.28 490.5 85.06c1.9-1.71 5.52-5.53 6.12-5.51s4.27 4.09 5.81 5.51c34.12 31.36 147.8 135.07 171.66 157l.57.52c2.7 2.47 5.53 4.82 8.11 7.42l96 87.85c30.13 27.54 60.36 55.11 90.25 82.26a60.38 60.38 0 0 1 8.26 8.57h-24.8c-7.89 0-18.6-1.68-24.48.61-6.4 2.5-5.2 10.13-5.2 19.89 0 81.12-.62 159.9-.61 240.51 0 6.24-.89 13.44.31 17.14 2.41 7.43 13.33 6.55 15.61 0 1.43-4.11.61-10 .61-15.61 0-16.18.31-34.41.31-49.26 0-66.19.21-133 .61-196.75h47.12c10.75 0 21.7 1.48 21.11-8.87z"/><g id="casa"><path id="c" class="cls-3" d="M434.81 490.8c-6.53 8.39-18.94-4.74-27.84 2.75-7.06 5.94-7.47 21.2-1.84 27.23 2.41 2.58 6.34 4.08 11.32 3.67 5.88-.48 14.39-6.58 18.36.31-14.42 16.69-48 8.79-47.73-17.14a25.87 25.87 0 0 1 23.56-25.7c11.45-1.07 18.68 3.26 24.17 8.88z"/><path id="a" class="cls-3" d="M477.95 502.13c-.45-7.71-5.35-11.23-13.46-10.4-7 .72-15.31 5.83-18.67-1.22 4.91-4.92 10.34-8.47 18.36-9.18 18.52-1.63 28.77 9.72 29.07 24.79.38 19-13.66 30.07-30.9 28.15-9.48-1.06-22.57-8.71-17.75-22.34 3.58-10.12 20.36-13.08 33.35-9.8zm-20.81 13.46c-2.3 10 13.13 10.7 18.05 4.9 2.18-2.57 2.65-5.58 3.06-9.18-7.18-1.69-19.56-2.43-21.1 4.28z"/><path id="s" class="cls-3" d="M542.52 491.72c-4.64 7.57-13.82-1.69-22.34-.92-2.48.22-4.42 1.18-4.59 3.37-.37 4.8 8.79 6.62 12.85 8.26 8.17 3.31 20.71 10.57 13.77 22.34-7.48 12.69-34.93 10.61-41.61-1.22 5.15-7.18 13.15 1.26 22.64.92 3.91-.14 8.15-1.17 8.26-4.9.07-2.44-3.23-5.13-5.51-6.43-7.64-4.34-19.28-6.15-22-13.77-4.16-11.52 6.93-17.77 16.83-17.75s17.55 4.66 21.7 10.1z"/><path id="a-2" data-name="a" class="cls-3" d="M584.44 502.13c-.76-4.65-2.24-7.91-5.51-9.49-8.47-4.1-21.89 6.79-26.62-2.14 5.8-6 13-10.23 25.09-9.18a24.32 24.32 0 0 1 22 22c.8 8.18-.86 17.66-8 24.17-11.6 10.79-42.43 9.79-41.23-11.29.79-13.92 18.85-17.56 34.27-14.07zm-21.11 15a6.73 6.73 0 0 0 4.28 6.43 12.74 12.74 0 0 0 17.13-12.28c-7.78-1.72-21.04-2.62-21.42 5.84z"/></g><g id="dupet"><path id="d" class="cls-2" d="M319.15 484.99c.21 6-.47 12.3-.92 18.67-1.35 19.22-.61 39.91-.61 60.89 0 26.87 2.51 56.67-6.12 75.89-8.54 19-23 31.68-46.51 35.49-44 7.13-73.66-20.86-75.58-61.5-1.67-35.29 18.6-60.66 46.2-68.24 14.71-4.05 34.71-2.91 47.71 4.59-.3-12.7-1.56-25.51-.61-35.8 1.73-18.53 14.83-30.32 36.44-29.99zm-79.83 85.37c-15.92 8.38-23.41 45-14.08 65.48 5.58 12.25 22.65 22.49 39.47 15.3 19.86-8.5 26.32-52.87 11.93-71.91a30.43 30.43 0 0 0-27.85-11.32 27.05 27.05 0 0 0-9.47 2.45z"/><path id="u" class="cls-2" d="M453.17 544.35c-4.42 32.84 3.09 68.8-6.12 94.24-8.32 23-28.57 40.75-61.5 38.25-29.34-2.23-47.48-20.52-55.38-45-4-12.52-3.67-30.83-3.67-46.51 0-16.42 4.06-28.58 14.38-35.49 5.44-3.64 13-4.6 21.11-5.51 2.1-.24 1.22 2.41.92 6.12-1.3 15.86-1.22 35.3-1.22 52.94 0 21.51 3.52 39.51 15.61 46.51 6 3.47 16.89 4.12 23.87.61 12.72-6.4 15.3-26.37 15.3-44.06 0-15-1.56-31.8 3.37-43.14 5.01-11.58 15.48-19.16 33.33-18.96z"/><path id="p" class="cls-2" d="M495.7 670.11c4 31.49-5.71 53.9-36.11 52.94 1.41-18.89 1.84-39 1.84-59.06 0-20.79-1.29-41.67.31-60.89 2.25-27 16.78-45.76 37.64-54.16a71.49 71.49 0 0 1 26.62-5.2c23.33-.17 40.71 9.66 50.79 23.87s16.5 36.73 11 59.67a65 65 0 0 1-32.13 42.53c-14.47 8.06-42.99 10.86-59.96.3zm16.83-99.45c-16.39 9.29-24 48.16-11.93 68.24 6.2 10.31 23.14 19.44 38.55 11.93 18.65-9.08 24.7-50.53 11.93-70.38-5.33-8.29-15.48-13.9-28.15-12.55-4.68.51-7.82 1.3-10.4 2.77z"/><path id="e" class="cls-2" d="M632.48 622.99c1.12 21.52 15 33.19 37.94 29.37 11.09-1.85 23.66-9.11 34-5.2 3.64 1.38 6.45 5 8.26 8a63.38 63.38 0 0 1-30.9 19.28c-13.9 4-31.38 3.59-44.06-.61-24-7.93-39.36-30.33-39.47-60.89-.14-39.3 22.28-64.64 57.53-68.85 28.75-3.43 53.89 9.21 60.59 29.37 4.72 14.2.45 29.84-8 38.25-14.71 14.66-49.05 19.57-75.89 11.28zm25.4-64.87c-.75 11-14.64 11.93-13.16 23.56 2.07 0 4.25-.17 4.59 1.53-2.74.53-5 1.5-7.65 2.14-3.93-3.68-11.75-2.88-18.67-3.67-5.37-.62-11-2.91-15.3 0a21.45 21.45 0 0 0 11.32 5.51c4.56.59 11.53.33 11.63 4.28 0 1.41-4.15 5.36-5.2 6.73-3.42 4.46-7.28 10.49-3.67 16.83 9.57-4.08 15.63-17.81 27.84-19.28 6.3-.76 9.72 2.28 15.91 1.84 1.31-.09 2.23-1 3.67-.31-4.9 3.14-10.59 5.47-11.32 12.85a27.49 27.49 0 0 0 1.22 10.1 51.44 51.44 0 0 0 11.63-14.38c1.51.63 1.19 3.1 1.84 4.59 2-2.28 2.93-7.55 1.53-11.32 12.6-3.11 24.7-6.71 30.9-16.22.55-.77 2-.64 2.45-1.53-1.72-1-1.53-1.92-.61-3.67-5.37-4.24-12.53-10-22.34-8.87-3.42.39-7.09 2.09-11 2.14-4.09-5.7-8.49-11.09-15.61-13.77v.92z"/><path id="t" class="cls-2" d="M720.6 486.21c32.94-1 40 23.86 37.64 58.14 12.86.62 27.33.2 38.86-1.53.84 24-14.9 31.41-38.86 30.6.54 28-3.56 60.21 12.24 73.13 6.94 5.68 22.27 7 33 2.45 4 19.28-11.59 28.15-27.23 28.46a45.7 45.7 0 0 1-26.93-8.27c-13.78-9.39-23.09-25.19-26-44.37-1.6-10.55-1.22-22.11-1.22-34 0-34-.67-71.43-1.53-103.73.1-.48-.49-.75.03-.88z"/></g><g id="cuidado"><path id="c-2" data-name="c" class="cls-3" d="M255.5 707.44c-4.44 3.76-9.2-.43-15-.31a18.55 18.55 0 0 0-18.36 16.52c-1.48 13.19 3.79 25.54 18.05 26 5.77.19 11.62-4.43 15.3 0-3.44 3.83-7.87 5.85-13.46 6.43-20.13 2.08-32.13-13.49-30.9-30.6 1-13.62 10.71-23.46 24.79-24.78 8.86-.82 15.79 1.78 19.58 6.74z"/><path id="u-2" data-name="u" class="cls-3" d="M266.21 719.99c1 9.64-3 34.35 10.71 29.07 10.2-3.94-2-30.58 15-29.07.22 19.86.43 37.22-18.67 36.11-8.59-.5-15.64-7.47-16.52-16.83s-.41-19.23 9.48-19.28z"/><path id="i" class="cls-3" d="M304.77 719.07c-.5 11.36-.5 24.74 0 36.11-2.6-.06-5.93-.7-7.65-2.45-3.51-3.56-3.88-27.2 0-31.21 1.75-1.81 4.65-2.44 7.65-2.45z"/><path id="_." data-name="." class="cls-3" d="M298.32 703.16c3.94-.85 5.89.86 6.43 3.06 2.13 8.79-13.3 10.5-10.71.31.34-1.25 1.82-2.84 4.28-3.37z"/><path id="d-2" data-name="d" class="cls-3" d="M342.4 701.63c-2.87 15.46 3.84 40.22-5.51 49.57-6.4 6.4-20 6.71-26.31-.61-12.13-14 2.64-39 21.73-29.68-.39-8.98-.77-20.55 10.09-19.28zm-15.91 47.73c9.4-2.8 8.6-25.11-3.67-23.56-11.83 1.48-9.71 27.55 3.67 23.56z"/><path id="a-3" data-name="a" class="cls-3" d="M367.8 733.45c-.69-3.89-2.22-6.64-5.51-7.34-5.75-1.22-14 5.19-16.83-.92a19.73 19.73 0 0 1 14.69-6.73c11.6-.18 17.32 7.56 18.05 16.52 1 12.34-7 21.64-18.67 21.73-8.47.06-19.7-6.58-14.69-17.14 2.95-6.19 12.64-8.19 22.96-6.12zm-13.48 14.38c4.52 4.42 14.8-.45 13.46-7.65-5.46-3.58-20.02 1.24-13.46 7.65z"/><path id="d-3" data-name="d" class="cls-3" d="M414.92 701.63c-2.87 15.47 3.85 40.22-5.51 49.57-6.4 6.4-20 6.72-26.31-.61-11.87-13.68 2.12-39.36 21.73-29.68-.41-8.99-.75-20.52 10.09-19.28zm-15.91 47.73c9.41-2.8 8.61-25.11-3.67-23.56-11.83 1.48-9.71 27.55 3.67 23.56z"/><path id="o" class="cls-3" d="M432.67 719.38c12.22-1.55 22.49 7.28 20.5 21.42-3 21.3-36.89 19.47-36.72-3.37.08-10.35 7.36-16.93 16.22-18.05zm-.92 29.68c13.7 5.64 16.72-25.22 2.14-23.26-9.17 1.24-9.98 20.03-2.14 23.26z"/></g><g id="completo"><path id="c-3" data-name="c" class="cls-3" d="M530.89 725.19c-4.61 6.09-10.81-1.62-17.44.92-8.06 3.09-7.45 20-.31 22.95 6.92 2.83 13.44-5.41 17.75.61-11.5 12.82-35.17 5-33-14.69 1.57-15.01 22.43-21.37 33-9.79z"/><path id="o-2" data-name="o" class="cls-3" d="M546.8 719.38c7.74-1 14.94 3 17.75 7.34a35.62 35.62 0 0 1 2.75 7c2.25 16-12.68 27.52-26.93 20.5-6.53-3.22-12.65-13-8.57-23.56a19 19 0 0 1 15-11.28zm4.9 30c8.73-2.8 8.29-25.21-3.67-23.56-11.03 1.46-9.71 27.83 3.67 23.54z"/><path id="m" class="cls-3" d="M598.82 723.97c5.91-7 20.53-5.77 25.7.92 5.77 7.46 2.64 19.65 4.28 30.29-17.93 1.82-3.64-28.89-17.14-29.68-11.58-.68-7.82 18.62-8 29.68-16.43 2-5.42-25-14.69-29.07-12.8-5.64-11.37 18.07-10.4 29.07-6.09-.13-9.38-3-10.1-8.26-1.74-12.63 3-26.61 15.61-27.85a18.66 18.66 0 0 1 14.74 4.9z"/><path id="p-2" data-name="p" class="cls-3" d="M640.43 754.28c.4 9 .68 20.44-10.1 19.28 2-18.88-4.28-43.74 8-51.71 12.88-8.39 29.11 1.75 28.15 17.14a18.08 18.08 0 0 1-26.05 15.29zm11-4.9c6.34-1.89 8.59-16.81 3.06-21.73a8.24 8.24 0 0 0-6.73-1.84c-11.65 1.41-10.09 27.66 3.69 23.55z"/><path id="l" class="cls-3" d="M668.32 701.63c18.69-.71 5.11 31.58 11.32 43.45 2.26 4.32 8.56 5.46 14.08 3.67 1.14 6.61-4.56 7.85-9.79 7.34a19.53 19.53 0 0 1-11.63-6.12c-7.66-9.51-2.24-32.78-4.28-47.43-.07-.43-.1-.86.3-.91z"/><path id="e-2" data-name="e" class="cls-3" d="M702.55 741.1c.62 5.13 2.77 8.24 7.34 8.57 5 .36 11.7-4.81 14.69 0-4.85 7.83-19.72 8.38-26.31 2.14-11.25-10.64-3.79-31.09 10.1-32.74 10.08-1.19 18.77 3.1 18.05 12.85s-13.39 11.53-23.87 9.18zm15.3-12.55c-2.57-6.77-17.73-2.05-15.3 6.73 6.46 2.41 18.24 1 15.3-6.72z"/><path id="t-2" data-name="t" class="cls-3" d="M738.04 719.07c3.65 0 7.53.19 10.4-.61 1.08 6.08-4.2 8.44-10.4 8.26-.91 11.82-.46 26.5 12.24 21.73 1.36 5.24-2.92 7.51-7 7.65-20.2.68-14.45-29.08-15.61-48.35a.47.47 0 0 0-.31-.61c7.22-.92 10.96 4.32 10.68 11.93z"/><path id="o-3" data-name="o" class="cls-3" d="M766.5 719.38c15.35-2.12 25 12.61 19.28 26-4.64 10.84-22.56 15.94-31.52 4-9.49-12.69-.57-28.23 12.24-30zm4.9 30c6-1.81 8.38-16.68 3.06-21.73a7.9 7.9 0 0 0-6.73-1.84c-11.23 1.71-9.29 27.47 3.67 23.55z"/><path id="_.-2" data-name="." class="cls-3" d="M793.73 745.08c8.23-1.13 7.29 11.35-.61 10.4-5.5-.66-5.94-9.5.61-10.4z"/></g><g id="animais"><path class="cls-3" d="M732.1 295.07a137.49 137.49 0 0 1-14.08 15c-.58 21.9 3 39.65 5.51 58.44-5-1.87-6.17-6.83-8.57-12.24-.8-1.8-2.38-4.84-3.37-7s-1.93-6.22-4-6.12c-2.44.12-3.53 8.88-4.28 11.32-1.4 4.57-2.07 8.15-5.51 9.79 1-3.84 2.62-8.58 1.53-13.46-2.47.37-3.45 3.5-5.2 5.51s-3.33 4.65-7 4.28c1.19-6.77 10.19-14.21 6.11-23.31-5.36 2.19-5.88 10.85-11.63 11.63.24-6.47 3.24-11.72 5.51-17.44 2-5.16 6-11.89 5.81-17.75-.11-3.94-3.15-9.49-4.59-13.77-4.46-13.27-7.73-30.62-2.45-46.51 1.31-7.28 7.34-16.83 7.34-16.83 2.66-5.61 9.75-13.3 15-19.58-5.09 1.57-13-7.54-13.77 1.53-4.61-1.41-6.74-7.92-5.2-13.16 1.14-3.89 5.5-6 8.57-7.34-2.22-12.37 21.26-16.92 30.6-11.32 22.54 13.51 27.72 66.8 12.86 92.88a122.84 122.84 0 0 1-9.19 15.45zM524.46 286.71a50.86 50.86 0 0 1 15.91 13.46c6.33.2 13.88-.83 17.75 1.84 3.17-1.72 4.44-5.35 5.81-8.87 1.32 3.84.82 7.8 1.84 11.32.58 2 2 4 2.75 6.12 2.18 6.24 2.86 15.09 5.51 21.11 2.87 6.52 10.23 11.17 17.75 12.55 6.43 1.18 11.32 1.35 16.22 3.06 13.73 4.81 23.49 14.23 30.9 26.31 9.12 14.86 14.33 37.1 10.4 63.34 6.35 1.4 13.46 1.53 20.19 1.53 14.17 0 26.95 2.81 38.55 6.12 6 1.7 12 4.05 18.36 3.67 8.47-.51 14.62-4.21 20.5-8 1.7-1.08 4.11-3.34 6.43-1.22.94 3.43-2.47 5.46-4.28 7-5.82 5.06-14.55 10.27-24.17 11-9.18.71-16.69-1.67-25.4-4.28-24.79-7.44-52.81-3.93-74.36 6.12-3.68 1.72-7.35 4.65-12.55 5.2a34.14 34.14 0 0 1-15.3-2.14c-3.82-1.49-8.24-4.25-13.46-4-3 .16-5.58 1.65-8.26 1.84-8.41.59-14-3.26-18.67-7.65-4.41 5.49-20.93 4.09-20.2-5.51.36-4.64 6.57-6.18 8-9.49 1.3-3.1 1.53-10.65 1.53-14.38a63.41 63.41 0 0 0-5.2-24.17c-2.82-6.57-7.43-12.46-10.1-19-4.08-9.95-2.32-22.25-.92-34.27-2.17-2.38-5.38-3.61-7.65-6.43-2.45-3-5.09-8.8-4.28-13.46.44-2.56 4.25-5.48 6.43-8s5-5.06 5.51-8.57c1.22-8.92-3.52-14.24-5.54-22.15zM389.22 222.15c-7.14 2.85-10.61 11-14.69 15.91-1.83-14.12 3.51-24.08 8.57-33.66 4.73-9 11.11-19.19 19.58-23.56a61.68 61.68 0 0 1 21.42-6.12 36.45 36.45 0 0 1 19.28 3.67c2.8 1.37 6.61 5 10.1 5.51 1.89.29 4.28-.45 6.73-.61 6.39-.42 14.56-.51 20.2-1.53 2.4-.44 4.7-2.07 7-1.22 1.85 6.64 3.43 15.46 0 22.95-5 10.83-16.3 20-27.84 22.95 1.24 14.57-.81 28.31-5.51 37.94 6.43 16.11 17.5 31.31 16.52 54.47-.28 6.57-2.5 12.42-4 19.58-1.59 7.69-1.3 16.43-1.84 24.79-1.29 20.19-1.92 43.6.61 63.65.5 3.92.81 8.7 1.84 11.32 1.27 3.24 5.73 5.19 7.65 8.26 1.28 2 3.08 5.85 2.75 8.87-.5 4.63-9.85 11.5-17.14 10.71-3.46-.37-12-4.64-13.16-7.65-.71-1.9.08-4.38 0-6.43-.2-5.21-1.94-11.19-2.75-17.14-1.53-11.17-3.12-23.45-3.67-35.49-.26-5.72 1.15-12.48-2.75-16.83-4.36 1.29-5.08 6.77-6.43 11-3.52 11.12-10 31.55-4.59 45 1.7 4.22 6 8 9.49 11 3 2.66 9.45 6.78 8 11.93-1 3.39-7.68 5-12.55 5.2-9.69.31-16.59-3.42-22.34-7-3.74.86-6.82 2.31-11 1.84-3.41-.39-6.1-2.37-9.18-2.45-4.81-.12-10.14 2.39-15.3 3.37-17.32 3.27-33.84.17-45.59-7-26.38 7.83-74.55 9.71-78-19.89-.37-.35-.12-.78 0-.31 12.85 16.57 54.4 18.19 72.21 4 2.34-1.87 6-4.94 6.43-7 .51-2.63-1-6.25-1.22-9.18-1.15-16.65 1.88-32.34 6.12-45.29 1.71-5.22 4.11-9.93 5.81-15 2.52-7.46 4.1-14.8 7-21.73 7.11-16.74 16.77-29.88 25.7-45.9 1.79-3.21 4.39-6.68 4.9-9.18.79-3.93.28-7.63.92-11a50.84 50.84 0 0 1 2.45-9.18c2.25-5.77 5.63-9.45 8.87-14.08-.39-9.75-1.43-19.55-.6-29.49z"/></g></svg></h1>
    </div>    
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="index.php" title="Home"><span data-hover="Home">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="produtos.php" title="Prices"><span data-hover="Produtos">Produtos</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="servicos.php" ><span data-hover="Serviços">Serviços</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="sobre.php" title="About us"><span data-hover="Sobre">Sobre</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contato.php" title="Contact us"><span data-hover="Contato">Contato</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No evento de scroll, você compara a altura da navbar com a posição do scroll. Se a posição do scroll for maior que a altura da navbar, você a esconde, senão exibe.

```
$(document).scroll(onScrollBody);
function onScrollBody() {
    var currentScrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
    //testar aqui se o a posição do scroll já é suficiente para esconder     
    //poderia ser assim, por exemplo:
    if(currentScrollTop > $('#menu').height()){
        $('#menu').hide();
    }
    else { $('#menu').show(); }
}
```

[jquery scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Não testei, talvez precise de alguns ajustes, mas a idéia é essa.

E talvez faça mais sentido você remover esse estilo fixed da navbar, então ela vai subir normalmente junto com o resto da página no scroll. Aí você testa a altura do scroll como no exemplo acima e não precisa esconder a navbar, pois ela já desapareceu naturalmente, você só exibe o botão citado e depois faz o movimento contrário, quando a altura do scroll for menor que a altura da navbar, você esconde o botão.